# Manage Google Assistant Actions programmatically

Tags: oauth, actions-on-google, google-console-developer

I'm trying to integrate my online Google Actions builder with Actions Console.

Now users have to manually create Actions JSON descriptor file and upload it to the project via gactions tool. But I would to let them upload their actions without these steps. As an example I saw that Gupshup service does this already - user has to authorise Gupshup once he would to upload his project, and all things perform behind the scene by Gupshup.

As I know I have to use some sort of Google API that allows to manage projects in Google Console with some specific OAuth scope - something like "Allow this service to manage Google Assistant dialogues and grammars".

Are there anybody who knows anything about such OAuth scopes and API?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something with the [gactions tool](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli), although there is no fully public API to manage Assistant console projects.

Comment: Gupshup makes this easily with OAuth, so there is some fully public API